# Is it possible to get systemd to monitor a process that it does not start?

Tags: systemd, service, startup, init, startup-scripts

Some of our startup scripts have an ExecStart line that runs a curl command to start jobs from our Jenkins build server.

Systemd does not know anything about the job that is started as a result of the curl command and therefore cannot give us a proper status for the job.  It also cannot stop the job.

I tried to get systemd to be aware of the job by specifying the PID file in the unit file of the service and adding an ExecPost line that would find the PID and add it to the specified location of the PID file.  This did not work.

Is there a way to make systemd aware of a process that it does not start?

Comment: That should have been a ExecStartPost not ExecPost.   It is correct in the unit file.  I just made a mistake in submitting this  post.

Comment: There is an edit button to fix mistakes below your post ...